# New "[tag:" syntax interferes with Markdown links

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, tag-links

Links in `[link text][number]` format don't work properly if they follow a tag using the new `[tag:tagName]` format. Here's the result of `[tag:python] [gold badge page][1]`:

> [python](/questions/tagged/python) [gold badge page][1](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/51/python)

Putting the tag inside the link is worse. Here's the result of `[[meta-tag:bug] some text][2]`, where `[2]` is `google.com`:

> [[meta-tag:bug] some text](http://google.com)

The part of the link outside the tag just disappears silently.

EDIT:
To be more precise, the entire link to `[2]` disappears. The markup that is produced contains (invalid) nested anchor tags, as shown here from Firefox's "View Source":

```
<a href="http://google.com" rel="nofollow"><a href="/questions/tagged/bug" class="post-tag required-tag" title="show questions tagged 'bug'" rel="tag">bug</a> some text</a>
```

So the tag is still a link, but it is a link to the tag page, which is the behavior it would have if the link to `[2]` didn't exist at all. The user's desired behavior in this case is... ambiguous, to be charitable.

EDIT 2:
*I briefly included markup from Firebug here, but it turned out to be irrelevant. It has now been removed to improve readability. See [the revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/70529/revisions) if you're interested.*

Comment: 10 years? Not a big deal, but also seems like it would be a pretty easy fix.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The <a>[tag:name]</a> generating bad html is mildly annoying, even if I don't really think its a valid use case.  I've gone ahead and checked in a fix to dev (we just won't process the tag syntax if it appears in an anchor tag).

The [tag] [text] [index] is actually by design.  The markdown spec allows a space between a link's text and its "index."  Its kind of a goofy use case, but its in there.

[Markdown Link Spec](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link)

> You can optionally use a space to separate the sets of brackets:
>   This is [an example] [id] reference-style link.

Comment: it's a *totally* goofy use case. I didn't even know that was supported!

Answer (score 20):

Case 1 can be worked-around by inserting **two** spaces after `[tag:python]`.

> ```
> [tag:python]  [gold badge page][1]
> ```
>
> [python](/questions/tagged/python)  [gold badge page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/51/python)

Comment: as Kevin pointed out this is because the markdown spec allows a space between `[link title][1]` .. much to my surprise.

Comment: Stranger yet! I *never* would have suspected *just one* space was allowed!

Answer (score 3):

Another way to work around this is to add the link in parentheses just like we do in comments.

For example:

```
[tag:support] [question from four years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152827/321647)
```

This gives: [support](/questions/tagged/support) [question from four years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152827/321647)

---

---

It's also possible to use the HTML space.

```
[tag:support]&#32;[question from four years ago][1]
```

Which gives the same result:

[support](/questions/tagged/support) [question from four years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152827/321647)