# A [tag:foo] followed by a hyperlink breaks the world

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New “[tag:” syntax interferes with Markdown links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70529/new-tag-syntax-interferes-with-markdown-links)

```
[tag:foo] [a hyperlink][1]
```

Results in; [foo](/questions/tagged/foo) [a hyperlink][1](http://google.com)

**Doh**

[image]

Comment: Come on Matt, to the Sandbox!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[foo](/questions/tagged/foo)  [a hyperlink](http://google.com)

It works if you use two spaces in between. o.o It has to do with links following the criteria `[alt_text] [link_name]` (with the space between) as well. It's likely looking at `[tag:foo] [a hyperlink]` first and saying `a hyperlink` is not a valid anchor from the list, so not rendering.

It seems that when there is a series of three bracketed pieces of text, it will always connect the first two. For example, `[tag:foo] [1] [1]` will produce:

[tag:foo](http://google.com) [1](http://google.com)

It looks at `[tag:foo] [1]` and `[1]` as separate links. So in the exmaple provided, it's looking at `[tag:foo] [a hyperlink]` as the first link, which is invalid, and `[1]` as the second link.

Likely they are calling their function to parse `[tag:*]` elements *after* they are calling their function to parse anchors, when it should be called before, or possibly the anchors parser should not match to link names which start with `tag:`.

Comment: I quoted you to answer a meta ELU post. https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10168/50044 What are your thoughts? Do visit it when you're able.

Answer (score 5):

Hm, interesting bug. In the meantime an inline link seems to work:

```
[tag:foo] [a hyperlink](http://google.com)
```

Results in; [foo](/questions/tagged/foo) [a hyperlink](http://google.com)

**Yey!**

[image: Unicorn FTW]

Comment: Damn you and your lovely pon^H^H^Hunicorns! I was about to say that...