# Two spaces are needed to create a link after a tag reference

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New “[tag:” syntax interferes with Markdown links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70529/new-tag-syntax-interferes-with-markdown-links)
>   [A [tag:foo] followed by a hyperlink breaks the world](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111694/a-tagfoo-followed-by-a-hyperlink-breaks-the-world)

For example, `[tag:bug] [link][1]` is formatted as follows.

> [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [link][1](http://google.com)

But [links should look like this](http://google.com).

Add an extra space between the tag and the link (`[tag:bug]  [link][3]`) and it works.

> [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)  [link](http://google.com)

Comment: @animuson good call, [this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70529/new-tag-syntax-interferes-with-markdown-links) is kind of a mess but kind of explains it? Apparently it is by design.