# A way to retract a comment flag?

Tags: support, comments, flags

Is there a way to retract a comment flag ?

Just did one thinking it was disguised advertising before realizing my mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't a way to retract a flag.

Don't worry about the specific flag you're referring to, I dismissed it. A comment pointing to a commercial product that's relevant(ish) to the question isn't really a bad thing, we point to commercial products all the time (I have several comments out there pointing to stuff like PHPStorm or JIRA, for example).