# Make it possible to retract comment flags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, comment-flags, retracted-flags

I misread the content of a comment, and flagged it. Then I realized that the comment wasn't what I had initially thought. Would it be possible to have the ability to retract comment flags, just like we have the ability to retract flags on questions and answers?

I'm aware of this [support](/questions/tagged/support) [question from four years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152827/321647). But the answer there is just that it's not possible. At the time it was not possible to retract *any* flags. [It is now, but not for comments.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281010/321647)

This is a separate [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) which requests that it may become possible to retract comment flags.

If I've realized a flag was a mistake, I think it's unnecessary to keep it in the queue of content the moderators have to look at. Also, it would add an unnecessary "rejected" to the flaggers statistics. Sure, people should think before they flag. But everyone makes mistakes sometimes.

Comment: "This does not work for comments as the issue of mis-flagging mainly happens on Questions & Answers" did you even read that answer?

Comment: @SomePerson Yes, I did read that answer. In this post I've explained that I've occasionally mis-flagged comments. I agree that it's probably less common. But since it does happen, the feature would be useful.

Comment: I'm adding `status-deferred` to this and have written it up internally to see if we can get this implemented.

Comment: Something that may help: Adding a pop-up box saying "Are you sure you want to flag this comment as such-and-such?". This may cause people to check just once more before flagging.

Comment: @Jǝssǝ That won't help, except for the first times. Eventually it will become a reflex to click "yes".

Comment: @Taryn any chances this will be considered or done soon?

Comment: @Taryn - If you're in a position to re-raise this, it'd be great. Same rationale as [retracting post flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87500/134069) (more [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188379/please-revisit-the-decision-not-to-let-people-remove-moderator-flags)). Example: I flag a comment unfriendly/unkind, original author also realizes it comes off wrong and fixes it, and I see it's fixed. No need to waste moderator time, I should be able to cancel my flag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cancel misclicked flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Hi. That question is for questions and answers, not comments. As discussed in OP, that question now has [tag:status-completed], but for comments it has not been implemented.

Comment: @Revetahw retracted the close vote, thanks for telling me. That explains why I couldn't retract a flagged comment, I was looking for an explanation on Meta and thought being able to retract flagged Qs and As was the same for comments as well.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yeah, it should be the same.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Happy to announce that ability to retract a comment flag is now live network-wide. If you can flag a comment, then you can retract that flag.

It works in a similar way to post flag retractions - click on the activated flag, and confirm in the resulting modal that you would like to retract the flag. Note: you cannot reflag the same flag on the same comment after retracting it - unless it is a custom flag, in which case you are allowed to reflag it.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Interesting on the custom flags - do you know what the reason is for the exception?

Comment: @DavidK I do not know the full reasoning, but I believe that it is along the lines of: custom flags allow data entry to specify what it is about, so you might retract and resubmit in order to amend what you are trying to report (since there is no other way to edit it in place). Or a totally new issue may have come up.

Comment: When flagging as rude or abusive, the comment disappears (or at least it has done that for me in the past). If the comment is not there, there won’t be a way to retract the flag.

Answer (score 6):

When you try to raise another flag, after your flag has been declined by a moderator, there will be a warning that reads:

> Your last flag was declined - please review (a link for flags for username) it before flagging this post!

It happened to me more than a few times and no big deal. There is no negative effect on your reputation and you won't be suspended for flagging an appropriate comment unless you do it for a hobby.

I understand why you are raising this issue, but please be careful when you are flagging. If you are not sure, you don't have to flag it. Let others take care of it. Also, comments are not the important part of Stack Exchange format and they are not designed to last long anyway.

If SE accepts your feature request, I would not object to it strongly, but what if users start to overuse or abuse flagging comments and cancelling them? I think cost outweighs benefit here.

Also, you need to note that questions could be edited for your retraction of a flag, but comments can't be edited after 5 minutes of posting.

Comment: "what if users start to overuse or abuse flagging comments and cancelling them? I think cost outweighs benefit here." ...What cost? And if there is (which I doubt) a problem with cancelling and reflagging simply limit it to only allow 1 reflag.

Comment: Ok, the cost of implementing the feature makes more sense (I though you meant the cost of using the feature), I don't see the any issue with abuse/overuse though

Comment: e.g. cost of excessive database calls or maintenance